# how to calculate averages of repeated records over a day using awk?

Tags: awk

Can anyone tell me how to use awk to calculate the average of each day ($2) repeated records using unique id ($1) and measurement ($3) records of the data set.
 The data set looks like as follows:

```
32070     2010-12-15    540  
32070     2010-12-15    546  
32070     2010-12-15    549  
32070     2010-12-17    579  
32070     2010-12-17    553  
25903     2010-12-15    556  
25903     2010-12-15    543  
25903     2010-12-15    564  
25903     2010-12-16    567  
25903     2010-12-16    583
```

I want to have an average of each day record ($2) based on measurement ($3) for each unique ID ($1) and print my output files separately to looks like as follows:

```
32070  2010-12-15    545  
32070  2010-12-17    566  
25903  2010-12-15     554.33  
25903  2010-12-16     575
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ curr = $1 OFS $2 }
curr != prev { if (cnt) print prev, sum / cnt; sum=cnt=0 }
{ sum+=$3; cnt++; prev=curr }
END { if (cnt) print prev, sum / cnt }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
32070 2010-12-15 545
32070 2010-12-17 566
25903 2010-12-15 554.333
25903 2010-12-16 575
```

The differences between this and @Ruslans answer are that:

1. His stores the whole input file in memory while the above just stores the value of the 4 variables (curr, prev, sum, and cnt) in memory.
2. His outputs the result in random (actually hash in most awk implementations) order while the above outputs the results in the order they appeared in the input.
3. His will work no matter what order your input occurs in while the above relies on your input being sorted by id and date.

Comment: the script just give me as it is with out averaging the daily records. I look forward your response. Thanks

Comment: You did something wrong when you copy/pasted it or your input isn't like the sample you provided. As you can see in my answer the script DOES do what you asked for given the sample input you provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN { SUBSEP = "@" }

{ a[$1,$2] += $3; n[$1,$2]++ }

END {
  for (x in a) {
    split(x, parts, SUBSEP)
    print parts[1] " " parts[2] " " a[x] / n[x]
  }
}
```

*Output*

```
25903 2010-12-15 554.333
25903 2010-12-16 575
32070 2010-12-15 545
32070 2010-12-17 566
```

**Explanation**

`SUBSEP` is an internal variable used to separate keys in [multidimensional arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html). Its default value is `"\034"` which is unlikely to appear in the input. I have set it to `@` in debugging purposes. You can skip modifying this variable.

The output will be in different order as compared to the "expected output". But you can easily sort it with `sort` tool by columns. For example, the following will sort the output by the second column, then by the first column (in that order):

```
awk -f script.awk file | sort -k2 -k1g
```

*Output*

```
25903 2010-12-15 554.333
25903 2010-12-16 575
32070 2010-12-15 545
32070 2010-12-17 566
```

This is just a sample. You should have got the general idea. Modify the commands according to your needs.

Comment: If you want to set SUBSEP to something, set it to OFS and then you don't need the `split()` and the `parts` array in the END section, you can just print the `x` indices as-is while getting rid of the hard-coded `" "` in favor of the normal `,` output separator.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks. I just wanted to show him the general idea. I find your advices useful, and I think the OP will find them useful, too.